# Shell Script String Manipulation

Tags: bash, shell, epoch

I'm trying to replace an epoch timestamp within a string, with a human readable timestamp. I know how to convert the epoch to the time format I need (and have been doing so manually), though I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace it within the string (via script).

The string is a file name, such as XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb.**1296066338**.gz (epoch is bolded).

I've been converting the timestamp with the following gawk code:

gawk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%Y%m%d.%k%M",1296243507)}'

I'm generally unfamiliar with bash scripting. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

thanks.

Comment: The way you are doing it is more than adequate. You could use BASH to knock off the EPOCH.gz and then tack on the formatting you want, but gawk is already doing that for you. Any particular reason why you want to change it?

Comment: Thanks Tim. My problem is that I didn't know how to use it in a script; specifically the renaming bit (and my poor regex skills don't help either). It probably sounds silly, but I could perform the same action in a heartbeat in Perl, but draw a blank when trying to translate it into shell. Here I thought Perl was supposed to be the more difficult of the two.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
date -d '@1296066338' +'%Y%m%d.%k%M'
```

in case you don't want to invoke awk.

Comment: thanks dtmilano. Awk is fine on the RH EL5 server I'm running this on, but it's nice to have an alternative; especially for the box I was testing this on (a Mac, sans awk/gawk)

Answer (score 0):

Are all filenames the same format? Specifically, "." + epoch + ".gz"?

If so, you can use a number of different routes. Here's one with sed:

```
$ echo "XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb.1296066338.gz" | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\)\.gz/\1/'
1296066338
```

So that extracts the epoch, then send it to your gawk command. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

...
epoch=$( echo "XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb.1296066338.gz" | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\)\.gz/\1/' )
readable_timestamp=$( gawk "BEGIN{print strftime(\"%Y%m%d.%k%M\",${epoch})}" )
```

Then use whatever method you want to replace the number in the filename. You can send it through sed again, but instead of saving the epoch, you would want to save the other parts of the filename.

EDIT:
For good measure, a working sample on my machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb.1296066338.gz"

epoch=$( echo ${filename} | sed 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\)\.gz/\1/' )
readable_timestamp=$( gawk "BEGIN{print strftime(\"%Y%m%d.%k%M\",${epoch})}" )

new_filename=$( echo ${filename} | sed "s/\(.*\.\)[0-9]\+\(\.gz\)/\1${readable_timestamp}\2/" )

echo ${new_filename}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash's string manipulation and AWK's variable passing to avoid having to make any calls to `sed` or do any quote escaping.

```
#!/bin/bash
file='XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb.1296066338.gz'
base=${file%.*.*}     #    XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb
epoch=${file#$base}   #    1296066338.gz
epoch=${epoch%.*}     #    1296066338
# we can extract the extension similarly, unless it's safe to assume it's ".gz"
humantime=$(gawk -v "epoch=$epoch" 'BEGIN{print strftime("%Y%m%d.%k%M",epoch)}')
newname=$base.$humantime.gz
echo "$newname"
```

Result:

```
XXXX-XXX-2011-01-25-3.6.2-record.pb.20110126.1225.gz
```